# Start XML parser

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

I am very new to Java/Android programming and need a little help with a part of code that I am writing. I have been following the "[Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)" article with no success.

The intent from "MainActivity.java" sends the string with XML text to my "ParsingXMLStringActivity.java" that I like to parse. Here is the string I successfully get over to the activity.

```
<action><app>survo</app><parameters><id>5666</id><p_t>205</p_t></parameters></action>
```

Now if wrote the public class XmlParser within the following "ParsingXMLStringActivity.java"

```
public class ParsingXMLStringActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parsing_xmlstring);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String receivedXMLstring = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.Authorize.XML_STRING);
    System.out.println("STRING:"+receivedXMLstring);
    InputStream in_stream;
    try {
        in_stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedXMLstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("STREAM:"+ in_stream);
        XmlParser XmlParser = new XmlParser();
        System.out.println("XmlParser:"+ XmlParser);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // OnCreate
    public class XmlParser {

    public final String ns = null;

    public List<Entry> parse (InputStream in_stream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_stream, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readAction(parser);
        } finally {
            in_stream.close();
        }           
    } // Public List Parse

    private List<Entry> readAction(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        List<Entry> action = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "action");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            // Starts by looking for the entry tag
            if (name.equals("action")) {
                action.add(readParameters(parser));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }  
        System.out.println("ACTION: "+action);
        return action;
    } // Public List ReadAction

    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
     } //Private Void Skip

    public class Entry {
        public final String id;
        public final String pt;

        private Entry(String id, String pt) {
            this.id = id;
            this.pt = pt;
        }
    } // public static class Entry


    private Entry readParameters(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "entry");
        String id = null;
        String pt = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("id")) {
                id = readId(parser);
                System.out.println("ID: "+ id);
            } else if (name.equals("p_t")) {
                pt = readPT(parser);
                System.out.println("P_T: "+ pt);
            }
            else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Entry(id, pt);
    } // Private Entry

    // Processes title tags in the feed.
    private String readId(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "id");
        String id = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "id");
        System.out.println(id);
        return id;
    }
    private String readPT(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "p_t");
        String pt = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "p_t");
        System.out.println(pt);
        return pt;
    }
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

The `System.out.println("ID: "+ id);` are not giving any information to the LogCat and I have set break points to check if the parser is even started but it does not seem to start the parsing process with the string I supply.

Does someone have an idea and can tell me what part I am missing???

Kind regards, Ben

Comment: start you XML string with the XML declaration as follows; <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: I have added this, it did change what is in the string variable "receivedXMLstring" but still has not reached any of the "System.out.println("ACTION: "+action);" where I have a Breakpoint set. It seems like it is not even getting there.